# A ParameterizedThreadStart Question: what, if a method is returning an object?

Tags: c#

I'm developing my own multithreading FTP Client. I have one method:

```
 public byte[] FileData;
 FileData = sendPassiveFTPcmd("RETR " + df.Path + "/" + df.Name + "\r\n");
```

which must be invoked in the new thread (e.g.):

```
ReadBytesThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(sendPassiveFTPcmd));
ReadBytesThread.Start("RETR " + df.Path + "/" + df.Name + "\r\");
```

as You noticed, it's obviously wrong declaration, because "sendPassiveFTPcmd" isn't returning "void" type. How to create a new thread with a method which returns an object ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get around delegate signatures, an anonymous method (or lambda) can help:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate (object state) {
    // call your method here!
});
```

You can also use captured variables to avoid the parameter completely... for example (using a lambda this time, and the overload that takes a `ThreadStart`):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => { /* your method */ });
```